# define constant variable in a structure initiation

Tags: c

I tried to follow the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875523/lookup-table-in-c) in order to initiate my data:

```
struct dmparam {
    char *p;
    char *v;
};

struct dmobj {
    int a;
    int b;
    const struct dmparam * const *dmparam;
};


const struct dmobj dmobj[] = {
    {1, 11, NULL},
    {2, 22,
        (struct dmparam  * const []) {//params
        {"p1", "v1"},
        {"p2", "v2"},
        }//params
    },
    {3, 33, NULL},
};
```

But I got warnings in the compilation

```
test.c:35:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
   {"p1", "v1"},
   ^
test.c:35:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[0]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:35:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:35:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[0]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:35:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
test.c:35:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[0]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:36:3: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
   {"p2", "v2"},
   ^
test.c:36:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[1]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:36:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:36:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[1]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:36:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
test.c:36:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)[1]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:38:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  },
  ^
test.c:38:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘dmobj[1].dmparam’) [enabled by default]
```

What I m missing?

Comment: Again this question? What do you expect to achieve with `(struct dmparam * const []) { ... }`? The `dmparam` of `struct dmobj` is a pointer to pointer to `dmparam`. Could you clarify your goals?

Comment: 1) Do not use the same name for types and variables/fields. 2) You need the address of the pointer.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: If that is a dup, do you have a link?

Comment: @Olaf He asked a question with very similar code 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014285/definition-of-structures-and-arrays

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Agreed. That is a dup and you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing two indexatation levels. `dmobj::dmparam` is (forgetting the const for the moment a `struct dmparam **` that is a pointer to a (const) pointer to a (const) `dmparam`.

Instead of initializing with a pointer to a pointer, the compiler tried to initialize directly with an array of `dmparam`. Clang warning is explicit : *incompatible pointer types initializing 'struct dmparam *const' with an expression of type 'char [3]'*. The compiler is not clever enough to guess what your wanted...

You must be explicit here:

```
const struct dmparam  params [] = {
        {"p1", "v1"},
        {"p2", "v2"},
};

const struct dmparam * const p = params;

const struct dmobj dmobj[] = {
    {1, 11, NULL},
    {2, 22, &p },
    {3, 33, NULL},
};
```

Here `params` is an array of `const dmparam`, `p` is a const pointer to `params` (another variable), and you put the address of `p` in `dmobj[1]`.